# Type Interface for Data structure

Tags: typescript, tsx

I have the following data structure print to the console after running this code snip

```
let editorDelta: DeltaStatic | undefined = editor?.getContents()
console.log(editorDelta)
```

console:

```
ops: [
  {
    attributes: {
      underline: true, 
      italic: true, 
      color: "#000fff", 
      background: "#fff000", 
      bold: true
    }, 
    insert: "this"
  },
  {
    attributes: {
      underline: true, 
      italic: true, 
      color: "#000fff", 
      background: "#fff000", 
      bold: true
    }, 
    insert: "that"
  },
]
```

I am attempting to create a type variable for this data but am running into some issues. The below interface is working but I would like to define types for some of the more nested data like attributes and insert ext.

```
interface DeltaStatic {
    ops?: object[]
}
```

Some other examples I have tried but do not work.

```
interface DeltaStatic {
  ops?: {
    attributes: {
      underline: boolean, 
      italic: boolean, 
      color: string, 
      background: string, 
      bold: boolean
    }, 
    insert: string
  }[] 
}
    
interface DeltaStatic {
  ops?: [
    {
      attributes: {
        underline: boolean, 
        italic: boolean, 
        color: string, 
        background: string, 
        bold: boolean
      }, 
      insert: string
    }
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An interface typically describes the shape of an object.  Assuming `editorDelta` is an object with the sole property `ops` on it, which has an array of objects like you've described, this will do:

```js
interface DeltaStatic {
  ops: {
    attributes: {
      underline: boolean;
      italic: boolean;
      color: string;
      background: string;
      bold: boolean;
    };
    insert: string;
  }[];
}
```

Keep in mind interfaces uses `;` to denote the end of an item, not `,`.

Comment: Doohh! sorry for the typo in my example. I have tried this however VSCode does not like it at all. I have been trying to get this to work all day with what in my mind should work just fine. But to no avail.

Just wanted to say thanks for the help and I guess I will need to look into this more.

Comment: Its a long list of 

Type 
'import("c:/Users/*/Documents/GitRep/*/node_modules/@types/quill/index").DeltaStatic | undefined' is not assignable to type 'DeltaStatic | undefined'.
  Type 'import("c:/Users/Christian/Documents/GitRep/lessondesigner/node_modules/@types/quill/index").DeltaStatic' is not assignable to type 'DeltaStatic'.
    Types of property 'ops' are incompatible.
      Type 'DeltaOperation[] | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ attributes: { underline: boolean; italic: boolean; color: string; background: string; bold: boolean; }; insert: string; }[] | undefined'.

Comment: What exactly is being returned by `getContents()`?  Is it an array, or is it an object with property `ops`, whose value is an array?

Comment: Its the latter, an object with ops property and array value 

`Delta {ops: Array(1)}`

Comment: With the original type that i created which only denoted the `ops:` property I can log `editorDelta?.ops` which returns an array of objects.

`(2) [{…}, {…}]`

Comment: Did you remove the `?` after `ops`? in the interface?  There's no reason to have it there, as the optionality comes from saying `DeltaOperation | undefined`

Comment: Yes the ? after `ops` in the interface has been removed.

Comment: Tough cookie my friend.  Seems like a simple problem but its hard to debug without seeing your full set up.  Can you reproduce the problem in a codesandbox?  Or in a TS playground?

Comment: I will try to get a codePen example working, If not I may end up having to bug a co-worker to figure this one out.  https://codepen.io/xzanos/pen/abBgVEP this is as far as I got but now `.getEditor` is not a function 

Answer (score 0):

```
type DeltaOperation = { insert?: any, delete?: number, retain?: number } & OptionalAttributes;

interface StringMap {
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface OptionalAttributes {
    attributes?: StringMap;
}

interface DeltaStatic {
    ops?: DeltaOperation[];
    retain(length: number, attributes?: StringMap): DeltaStatic;
    delete(length: number): DeltaStatic;
    filter(predicate: (op: DeltaOperation) => boolean): DeltaOperation[];
    forEach(predicate: (op: DeltaOperation) => void): void;
    insert(text: any, attributes?: StringMap): DeltaStatic;
    map<T>(predicate: (op: DeltaOperation) => T): T[];
    partition(predicate: (op: DeltaOperation) => boolean): [DeltaOperation[], DeltaOperation[]];
    reduce<T>(predicate: (acc: T, curr: DeltaOperation, idx: number, arr: DeltaOperation[]) => T, initial: T): T;
    chop(): DeltaStatic;
    length(): number;
    slice(start?: number, end?: number): DeltaStatic;
    compose(other: DeltaStatic): DeltaStatic;
    concat(other: DeltaStatic): DeltaStatic;
    diff(other: DeltaStatic, index?: number): DeltaStatic;
    eachLine(predicate: (line: DeltaStatic, attributes: StringMap, idx: number) => any, newline?: string): DeltaStatic;
    transform(index: number, priority?: boolean): number;
    transform(other: DeltaStatic, priority: boolean): DeltaStatic;
    transformPosition(index: number, priority?: boolean): number;
}
```